# Is there canon of the Doctor (or other timelords) getting drunk?

Tags: doctor-who

In "[The Girl in the Fireplace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_in_the_Fireplace)" The Doctor pretends to be drunk

I'm curious if there are other (canon) examples of him or other Timelords getting drunk or even if they *can* get drunk?

Comment: [Mandatory link](http://teatimebrutality.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/canon-and-sheep-shit-why-we-fight.html).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uz9JKbSkUW8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In "[Aliens of London](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/27-4.htm)", the Doctor indicates that he drank extensively with former PM, Lloyd George, suggesting that he can tolerate alcohol in heroic quantities:

> **ROSE:** *Oh, don't you just love it.*
>
> **DOCTOR:** *I'm telling you. Lloyd George, **he used to drink me under the table**. Who's the Prime Minister now?*

In the prose novel "[The Quantum Archangel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quantum_Archangel)", there's a rather more fulsome description of the effects of alcohol on a Galifreyan physique:

> Soon after he had settled into this body the Doctor had  discovered
>   that he once again liked the odd tipple. His Fifth  incarnation, up
>   there on his rented high moral ground, had  been virtually teetotal,
>   but the Sixth Doctor relished both the  taste and effects of alcohol.
>   True, **his Gallifreyan metabolism could overcome the effects in a
>   trice,** but it was still highly enjoyable getting drunk. Sometimes, it
>   was good to get away  from it all

and in the prose novel "[The Sorcerer's Apprentice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sorcerer's_Apprentice_(novel))", the Doctor's granddaughter Susan confirms that the effects of alcohol on Galifreyans is subject to intentional control

> ‘I wouldn’t have too much wine, if I were you, Susan. You might regret
>   it in the morning.’
>
> She blinked in incomprehension for a moment, and
>   Ian had the feeling she was translating an unfamiliar concept. Then
>   she replied simply: **‘Oh, it doesn’t matter what I drink. We don’t 
>   get inebriated. Unless we want to, of course.’**

Answer (score -1):

It is said that during the Feast of Rassilon, Time Lords and Gallifreyans are allowed to have ginger because it reduces their tolerance to alcohol. They sometimes have ginger beer on holidays.

Comment: Do you have a quote to back-up what you're saying?